# Should men attend a conference that suggests that it is only for women?

Tags: professionalism, gender, conferences

While I was an intern there was a Women's Leadership Conference hosted by the corporate offices in California. As an intern I wanted as many opportunities to network and gain insight as to how the company operated and its culture.

When I asked my supervisor if I could attend however, the responses were along the lines of "No, not really, its for women". Now at that time, I wasn't knowledgeable of the greater political and social implications of such conferences and events so I wrote it off. They wanted me to focus on my work (data cleaning) and left it at that.

Looking back however, was such a decision justified or reasonable? From a business perspective and event function, although the event didn't specify that men were excluded, I can rationalize that the greater business value was the work itself rather than its tradeoff of allowing an intern to attend a function (and thereby lose a day's work). But at the same time, wouldn't the exclusion based on gender in of itself be well... wrong?

Comment: Inspired by [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/99752/may-a-man-attend-a-workshop-whose-title-suggests-that-it-is-held-for-women)? I think answers would depend on the purpose/description of the conference. Who else from the company was sent?

Comment: Actually, yes. I frequent academia and the question did remind me of a situation not too long ago. As far as the conference, the goal was to encourage women to take leadership roles within the company. As the company was a fairly male-dominated leadership. As far as who was sent, if memory serves, the office was essentially empty. The only people that didn't go were interns or male employees.

Comment: @FrankFYC Is there any similar clarification regarding this point on the website/brochure/company communication for this conference?

Comment: @Myles Check the first version before it was edited.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If they put "Women" in the title, they want only women. Whether it's gender based exclusion is irrelevant.

If you had gone, you would have alienated nearly everyone there. It's not targeted at you. The same thing would happen if you went to a meeting of the Association of Black Professionals.

But since this wasn't just you dropping on something as an interested party but something that your organization sponsored, I'm certain your attendance would have made you a pariah.

Comment: I think there is a difference between an independent association with clear membership limits and a conference seeking to promote a goal.  If you want to promote a goal of a mixed leadership environment, wouldn't it help to have a mixed group working on it.

Comment: @cdkMoose they can achieve that goal and limited it to Women also.

Comment: @cdkMoose mixed leadership environment might be the ultimate goal, but a targeted conference such as this is typically intended to recognize women in the organization as well as focus on a segment of their workforce that is historically severely underrepresented.

Comment: Not sure what's 'typical'. I've seen similar conferences that actively involved men in the proceedings. Just pointing out that using the word "women" in the title doesn't automatically make it exclusive

Answer (score 4):

I think it's justified.  As the conference organizers made it clear their intended audience is women a company would need to be very tone deaf to send male employees.  This would have potentially hurt the image of the company.

"ABC Company is so out of touch with empowering women in a workforce that they sent a male intern to the Women's Leadership Conference" would be an accurate sound bite whether it's fair or not.  From a risk versus reward perspective they have people who they can send to represent company interests that present much lower risk.

Comment: Not clear to me from the title that they intended only women to attend.  If any minority wishes a bigger seat a the table, wouldn't it make more sense to engage the majority instead of excluding the majority.  Work apart -> grow apart, work together -> grow together.